# Heapsort, heap "correctness"

Tags: c++, heapsort

My question is whether or not a heap can be "correct". I have an assignment asking me to do a heap sort but first build a heap using an existing array. If I look through the grader code it shows me that there is an exact answer. The way T implemented the heap build I get a slightly different answer but as far as i know is by definition a heap and therefore correct.

The "correct" array order is

```
{15, 12, 6, 11, 10, 2, 3, 1, 8}
```

but I get

```
{15, 12, 10, 11, 2, 6, 3, 1, 8}
```

The original vector is

```
{2, 8, 6, 1, 10, 15, 3, 12, 11}
```

```
void HeapSort::buildHeap(std::vector<CountedInteger>& vector)
{    
std::vector<CountedInteger> temp;
for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
{
    temp.push_back(vector[i]);
    fixDown(temp, i);

}
vector.swap(temp);
for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout<< vector[i]<<std::endl;

}
}

void HeapSort::sortHeap(std::vector<CountedInteger>& vector)
{
}

inline unsigned int HeapSort::p(int i)
{
    return ((i-1)/2);
}

void HeapSort::fixDown(std::vector<CountedInteger>& vector, int node)
{

if(p(node) == node) return;

if(vector[node] > vector[p(node)])
   {
       CountedInteger temp = vector[node];
       vector[node] = vector[p(node)];
       vector[p(node)] = temp;
       fixDown(vector, p(node));
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `heap can be correct`?

Comment: Probably, "Can more than one heap satisfy the heap constraint?" for a particular array of numbers.

Comment: He means: "For every possible source array of comparable elements, is there exactly one, or possibly more than one, valid heap structure representation?"

Comment: I think Irfy read my mind the best here

Comment: Since there are N! possible orders, and there are only (N*N-N)/2 ordering constraints, the pigeonhole principle tells us that for large enough inputs there MUST be multiple orders that satisfy the heap constraints. (and Dietrich Epp shows us that this is already the case for N=3)

Answer (score 4):

There are many possible ways to create a max-heap from an input.  You give the example:

```
15, 12, 10, 11, 2, 6, 3, 1 8

          15
    12          10
 11     2     6     3
 1  8
```

It fulfills the heap criterion, so it is a correct max-heap.  The other example is:

```
15, 12, 6, 11, 10, 2, 3, 1, 8

          15
    12           6
 11    10     2     3
 1  8
```

This also fulfills the heap criterion, so it is also a correct max-heap.

**Max-heap criterion:** Each node is greater than any of its child nodes.

A simpler example is `1, 2, 3`, for which there are two heaps,

```
  3       3
 / \     / \
1   2   2   1
```

Comment: @Dreken105: Yep!! All you need is to make sure the properties of a max/min heap are not violated at any time of creation.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a heap out of an array is *definitely* an operation that can result in multiple different but valid heaps.

If you look at a [trivial example](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Max-Heap.svg), it is obvious that at least some subtrees of one node could switch positions. In the given example, 2 and 7 could switch positions. 25 and 1 could also switch positions. If the heap has minimum and maximum depth equal, then *the subtrees of any node* can switch positions.

If your grader is automatic, it should be implemented in a way to check the heap *property* and not the exact array. If your grader is a teacher, you should formally prove the correctness of your heap in front of them, which is trivial.